# log file parsing python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a log file with arbitrary number of lines. All I need is to extract is one line of data from the log file which starts with a string “Total”. I do not want any other lines from the file.

How do I write a simple python program for this?

This is how my input file looks

```
TestName     id         eno            TPS      GRE          FNP
Test 1205    1            0            78.00        0.00         0.02
Test 1206    1            0            45.00        0.00         0.02
Test 1207    1            0            73400        0.00         0.02
Test 1208    1            0            34.00        0.00         0.02

Totals       64           0            129.61       145.64       1.12
```

I am trying to get an output file which looks like

```
TestName     id      TPS         GRE
Totals       64      129.61      145.64
```

Ok.. So I wanted only the 1st, 2nd, 4th and 5th column from the input file but not others. I am trying the list[index] to achieve this but getting a IndexError: (list index out of range ). Also the space between 2 columns are not the same so i am not sure how to split the columns and select the ones that i want. Can somebody please help me with this. below is the program I used

```
newFile = open('sana.log','r')

for line in newFile.readlines():

    if ('TestName' in line) or ('Totals' in line):

        data = line.split('\t')

        print data[0]+data[1]
```

Comment: Python seems like overkill for this task...wouldn't grep be quicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
theFile = open('thefile.txt','r')
FILE = theFile.readlines()
theFile.close()
printList = []
for line in FILE:
    if ('TestName' in line) or ('Totals' in line):
         # here you may want to do some splitting/concatenation/formatting to your string
         printList.append(line)

for item in printList:
    print item    # or write it to another file... or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in open('filename.txt', 'r'):
    if line.startswith('TestName') or line.startswith('Totals'):
        fields = line.rsplit(None, 5)
        print '\t'.join(fields[:2] + fields[3:4])
```