# advice on how to do a large find and replace with variable data in the block of text

Tags: text, replace, find

Can someone suggest a tool to use to take a large log file and do a find and replace to remove a bunch of log items that I don't need so I can find the small amount of relevant items? The issue is some of the text is always static but several parts are variable. Below is an example of an entry from the log file where the items in bold are what can change for each item.

---

**2013 Nov 27 10:55:58 AM**
In Method: ProcessXMLMessage
Error #: -2147217833
Description: String or binary data would be truncated.
SQL: INSERT INTO FOO(PID, RECORDID, REASONID, REASONTEXT) VALUES(**1884596, 1, 4, 'I like eggs'**)

```
Mode: Insert
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for a large file tool: UltraEdit: http://www.ultraedit.com/

Suggestion for a solution: Python - writing a script to parse the log file to find static message tags with dynamic content - to parse or change into a new filtered file. Here is one example: [log file parsing python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946051/log-file-parsing-python) but you should be able to find many more.

If you use a large file editor you will need to write some sort of script to do what you are talking about. Python is really easy to pick up, you could have this written in a couple hours even if you are a novice programmer. https://www.python.org/download/

Hope this helps,

Tim

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll have a look at Ultraedit.  If I wanted to be a narcissist I could try and dust off my old regexp knowledge but am trying to be lazy and find a GUI tool to let me do this. :)

Comment: I wound up using Ultraedit and checked the regex option box in the replace dialogue and used the following replace text and it worked great for me.----------------------------------------------------
2*
In Method: clsMessageXML9929.Initialize
Error #: 0
Description: XML Load Error
Detail: Bad xml - unable to initialize oXMLMessage.*

PCRMessage State
    PCRID: *
    MessageID: *
    MessageBody: *
    MessageType: *
    TabletID: *
    ServerID: *

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the lines which have this static text take a look at [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). As an example:

```
grep -v ProcessXMLMessage logfilename
```

should give you all lines in the file calles `logfilename` which do not have `ProcessXMLMessage` on its line.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  It is actually a larger block that makes up each log item and it spans multiple lines (e.g. CRs at end) as well some items have parts that have some of the same static text.