# Need to parse a tool log file in python and then save the results in excel or csv

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I need to parse below log file in Python:

```
Log file created: 9/10/2014 4:03:21 PM
----------------------------------------
Ticks = 2408967      <3360> <UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo> <0> Avg Prefetch(ms): 157.739, Avg Render(ms): 25.7375, Avg Display FPS: 27.3688
Ticks = 3371181      <3360> <UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo> <0>  Frames dropped during playback: 0 / 219, Preroll(ms): 812.849
Ticks = 3371181      <3360> <UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo> <0> Avg Prefetch(ms): 17.1389, Avg Render(ms): 33.8339, Avg Display FPS: 29.5562
Ticks = 3465531      <10548> <Assert> <0> Debug Assert failed!
Ticks = 3465531      <10548> <Assert> <0> wglMakeCurrent failed: Error 0: The operation completed successfully.
```

I need to extract `<UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo>` and `<Assert>` records, each with its constituent fields, and save them as an Excel or a CSV file.

Could anyone help me out to do this.

Comment: Parse how? What do you want to extract?

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I want to extract <UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo> and <Assert> values as of now. Please help.

Comment: and do what with them? Just list them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946051/log-file-parsing-python this question might help.

Comment: Yes, I need to list them, only thing here is that the format of the log file is different from that link you provided. I need to use regular expression here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the values enclosed by the inequality signs are, so I have replaced them with `foo` and `bar`. Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
import re
import csv

filtered_messages = ['UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo', 'Assert']
fieldnames = ['ticks', 'foo', 'type', 'bar', 'message']

with open('log.txt') as log:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))
        for line in log:
            match = re.search(r'^Ticks = (?P<ticks>\d+)\s+<(?P<foo>\d+)> <(?P<type>\w+)> <(?P<bar>\d+)>\s+(?P<message>.+)$', line)
            if match is not None and match.group('type') in filtered_messages:
                writer.writerow(match.groupdict())
```

Output (as CSV):

```
ticks   foo type    bar message

2408967 3360    UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo    0   Avg Prefetch(ms): 157.739, Avg Render(ms): 25.7375, Avg Display FPS: 27.3688

3371181 3360    UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo    0   Frames dropped during playback: 0 / 219, Preroll(ms): 812.849

3371181 3360    UpdatePlaybackStatusInfo    0   Avg Prefetch(ms): 17.1389, Avg Render(ms): 33.8339, Avg Display FPS: 29.5562

3465531 10548   Assert  0   Debug Assert failed!

3465531 10548   Assert  0   wglMakeCurrent failed: Error 0: The operation completed successfully.
```